# catalog_product_entity_decimal table is empty

Tags: special-price

I need to bring in cost, price and special_price into an existing query. Research brings back catalog_product_entity_decimal has special_price and price.
This table is empty.

Is there another table that houses this information?
And should this table be populated?

Magento version is 2.3.5

Answer (score 0):

Magneto follows Entity–attribute–value model. However if you are fetching the collection of the product or object of the product then you get this information. Why are you writing a sperate query for it?

Answer (score 0):

I might not have written this correctly.
We want on table compiling multiple queries from Magento and Netsuite (ERP), including the Price lists.
It would be a data dump of item setup in magento to ensure that fields have the correct information.
Thank you for replying.  I do not see this one, but will get with my IT dept to research.